# How event timestamp is measured (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, timestamp, data-import, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to import data into GA4.

I've done it successfully but it turns that my timestamps were wrong, so it shows my data as it occurred today (even though the is data from multiple months).

I've seen the documentations for the timestamp -
[image from GA4 import data documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Lxl.png)

I've failed to understand how my dates can be converted to their format.
this is mine:
[My timestamp micros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9K5J.png)

Edit:
I figured it, Time is in Epooch (micro seconds since 1970)
too bad the documentations can't specify it...

Also, Data cannot be imported as earlier than the day of the import.

Comment: Can you show us what have you have tried?